# Deploy Django Code with Docker to AWS EC2 instance without ECS

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

Here is my setup.

1. My Django code is hosted on Github
2. I have docker setup in my EC2 Instance
3. My deployment process is manual. I have to run git pull, docker build and docker run on every single code change. I am using a dockerservice account to perform this step.

How do I automate step 3 with AWS code deploy or something similar.

Every example I am seeing on the internet involves ECS, Fargate which I am not ready to use yet

Answer (score 0):

Check this out on how to Use Docker Images from a Private Registry (eg. dockerhub) for Your Build Environment
[How to Use Docker Images from a Private Registry for Your Build Environment](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/how-to-use-docker-images-from-a-private-registry-in-aws-codebuild-for-your-build-environment/)